# What is the meaning of flexible?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Harry: You a religious man, Norman?
>
> Norman: Atheist. But I'm **flexible**.

What flexible means in terms of religious matter?

Comment: [Flexible](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flexible): able to change or be changed easily

Comment: Not dogmatic, in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Flexible* is being used like this context:

> A: What time can you meet with me?
>
> B: 2pm.  But I'm flexible.

B prefers 2pm but is willing to at least hear other times that A would like to meet if 2pm doesn't work for A.

In your provided example, Norman is telling Harry he is an atheist, but would probably still pray to God and possibly perform other religious rituals if around others that did so.